# How to speed up picturebox graphics

Tags: c#, winforms, performance, graphics

I have a program that takes some information from databases and represents it graphically via pictureboxes in a form. Each piece of data is a differently colored picturebox and it basically looks like defragmenter.

For example

[image: Example display]

The program uses a loop to go through specific chunks of the database and represents it graphically.
The problem is, for large amounts of data/pictureboxes, it takes quite some time to draw them all (e.g. >20 seconds for few thousand, and even crashes a program for over 10,000 data pieces).

Is there a way to make a program draw those graphics in less then a second or close to it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can draw them yourself. Instead of having a lots of picture boxes, just use the `Paint` event of the control where you want to show them.

The event handler will get a [`Graphics` object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Drawing.Graphics%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for the control that you can use to draw the boxes. You can use the [`FillRectangle` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.fillrectangle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to draw the boxes.